# Why are <sup> and <sub> html elements not displayed in my flutter app using the flutter_html package?

Tags: html, flutter

the flutter_html package is supposed to enable displaying html elements properly. But when I try to render a simple example, (or the example provided on github) the sub and sup elements aren't displayed.
(Not just shown incorrectly but rather not displayed at all). Neither does
Android Studio throw any warning/error

I'm running the latest version of Android Studio on Ubuntu 18.4.
The problem appears when installing the example app and an emulated Pixel 2 with Android 9.0, as well as on an Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017).
I opened an issue in the flutter_html github repo, but after asking for additional information the author remained silent.

the main.dart file in the flutter project looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Html(
            data: """
            <body>
      <div>x<sup>2</sup></div>
      </body>
  """,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and in the pubspec.yaml I wrote:

```
flutter_html: ^0.10.4
```

the main.dart results in:

```
x
```

instead of:

```
x^2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the "`HtmlRichTextParser`" doesn't seems to support "`<sup>`" and "`<sub>`", but is enabled by default. By setting

`Html(
useRichText = false,
...`

in the c'tor of the Html widget, the example is displayed correctly.